# Mongoose promise in user provider object with prototype functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

Sorry i couldn't come up with a straight forward question/title, but here's the thing. I have the following construct:

```
var userProvider=function(login){
   this.getUser=mongoose.find(login).exec();
}
userProvider.prototype.doStuffWithUserData=function(){
   this.getUser.then(function(user){
       ...
   });
} 
userProvider.prototype.doOtherStuffWithUserData=function(){
   this.getUser.then(function(user){
       ...
   });
}
```

Is there a a nicer way, such that i don't need to call the promise in every prototype function, though the prototype functions being evaluated only until the data is there?

Comment: If you're repeating it you can extract it into a decorator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) - if that helps to solve your problem I'll gladly close as a dupe, if not I can post an answer with the decorator technique that Benjamin mentioned.

Comment: i'd go with the bad practice case, thanks :)

Comment: @Bergi His constructor doesn't return a promise though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: You're right, but it seems to be same setup - methods are relying asynchronous sideeffects done in the constructor. Sure, we don't know what `doStuff` and `doOtherStuff` exactly is, but they better not try to manipulate the instance or call other methods; otherwise this class would get a complete mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a a nicer way, such that the prototype functions being evaluated only when the data is there?

I'd recommend not to execute the `find` sideeffect in the constructor and *create* the promise there, but get the result of the `mongoose.find(login).exec()` passed into the constructor, as laid out in [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

> I'd go with the bad practice case

To avoid the repetition, you can create your prototype methods like this:

```
function userProviderMethod(n, m) {
    UserProvider.prototype[n] = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
            that = this;
        return this.getUser.then(function(user) {
            args.unshift(user);
            return m.apply(that, args);
        });
    };
}

function UserProvider(login){
    this.getUser = mongoose.find(login).exec();
}
userProviderMethod("doStuffWithUserData", function(user /*, … */) {
    // …
});
userProviderMethod("doOtherStuffWithUserData", function(user) {
    // …
});
```

Notice that none of these "methods" will actually ever get executed when `.getUser` did get rejected.

Comment: Heh, we came up with practically the same solution 20 seconds apart. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with decoration. This is tricky because the promise is not available when you create the function yet:

```
function whenReady(fnToRun){
    return function runsWhenReady(){ // the decorated function
        // keep track of arguments
        var args = Array(arguments.length + 1); // inline slice is much faster
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments[i]; i++) args[i+1] = arguments[i];
        return this.getUser.then(function(user){
            args[0] = user;
            return fnToRun.call(this, args); // append user and call with args
        }.bind(this)); // maintain context)
    };
}
```

This would let you do:

```
userProvider.prototype.doStuffWithUserData = whenReady(function(user){
    // user is available here 
});

myUserProviderInstance.doStuffWithData(); // inside the call user is available

userProvider.prototype.otherStuff = whenReady(function(user, x){
    // user is available here 
});

myUserProvider.otherStuff(15); // x will be 15 and user will be available, promise returned
```

This approach can be generalized to a more general `whenReady` that takes a "waitFor" argument. It's also worth mentioning that if you use a library like Bluebird it already ships with `bind` and `method` which let you do this in a more easy way.

Comment: You could do `var args = new Array(1)` so that you can avoid the `concat` call and do an assignment instead, if you really want to aim for speed :-)